# ARM Assembly instructions with Operand2 greater than 8 bits?

Tags: assembly, arm

Trying to `cmp r0, #350` and it says 350 cannot be represented in Operand2 format. I'm assuming its because 350 is greater than 8 bits. How do I compare with 350??

Comment: Actually, it would be wrong to assume that it can't be done because 350 is greater than 8 bits; its because 350 occupies odd number of bits (9 bits) which can't be generated by ARM as it involves the notion of rotate in representing the immediate. For details check my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to load the constant into a register beforehand and then compare the registers.

Try something like

```
ldr r1, =350
cmp r0, r1
```

The disassembly of this then looks like this

```
   0:   e51f1000    ldr r1, [pc, #-0]   ; 8 <.text+0x8>
   4:   e1500001    cmp r0, r1
   8:   0000015e    .word   0x0000015e
```

It stores the constant at the end of the symbol and uses pc-relative accesses to load it into a register.

Comment: I thought you used `=` for memory addresses and `#` for constants

Comment: In this case, the part after the equals isn't a symbol name, so you're not loading the address of the symbol. You're loading a constant.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I have `.equ Max 350` and I use that, it's considered a constant?

Comment: Sure, but that's really just a macro, it won't fix your `cmp` problem

Comment: OK I'll just use another register

Comment: bits is bits, address, constant, etc, they are just bits, ldr r1,=some_bits...yes it is pseudo code. you can load that value, 350, manually if you dont like using pseudo code...

Comment: It's somewhat complicated dealing with immediate values on ARM. 12 bits are assigned for an immediate value, 8bits for the pattern and 4bits for its position. 2^4=16. So if your immediate value can be expressed via a byte rotated by an even number, it's ok. Otherwise, not ok. 350 == 175<<1 ==>fail. 352 == 88<<2 ==> ok

Comment: If you have enough spare registers, it's ok assigning a register for that purpose, but if not, and you are forced to resort to swap on stack due to the lack of a single free register, you should really ask yourself if it absolutely has to be 350 since a single stack swap within a loop will seriously cripple the performance, far more than you might think.

Comment: Or even better, you should try to live without a single cmp-like instruction within a loop. It's possible in many cases through clever algorithms and data structures. That's what assembly programmers do all the day.

Comment: Also consider something like:
`ldr r1, #320
add r1, #30
cmp r0, r1`

This often faster than fetching from memory.
However it makes maintaining code a pain.
In a loop attempt to set the compare register before the loop and leave it alone. If you cannot then certainly try to avoid a memory fetch for performance reasons.

Using '=' versus '#' for the immediate. '=' will attempt to create the constant in a single instruction but load it otherwise whereas '#' will fail during assembly if it cannot create the constant.

Comment: @SilverCode, I have to disagree with you there. Using `=` won't try and create the constant in a single instruction. `ldr r1, =320` is a psuedo instruction where the compiler will add the constant at the end of the subroutine and load it into the register at runtime. It doesn't 'create' the constant like `mov` does. And going to your performance issue, I don't think it matters too much. In the end, you're still fetching two words to load the constant - whether you load two instructions to build the constant or load one instruction and one data word. Also your ARM assembly isn't valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand why 350 cannot be represented in Operand2 format, you have to understand how ARM uses the immediate operand field ,i.e. the last 12 bits.

1. One of the obvious ways is to use those 12 bits to represent the numbers as they are. For example if the last 12 bits are :

> 000001011010

then corresponding number that would be contained can be obtained by just converting the above binary numbers into the decimal equivalent which is 90 in this case. Doing this way we can only get a continuous sequence of numbers(integers) having 2^12 (= 4096) numbers, like 0 to 4095 or -2048 to 2047.

2. Another way that ARM architect came up with was that of the notion of 'rotate right'. This enabled to store numbers way beyond the restriction of having 12 bit numbers. In this, out of those 12 bits which are reserved for immediate is split into two fields, called the rotate (the top four bits) and the value (stored in the lower eight bits). The value is an eight bit number representing 256 possible combinations. The position is a four bit field which determines where in the 32-bit word the value lies.Note that now instead of 12 bit, you can store numbers having 32 bits! Below is a diagram showing how the sixteen values of the position determine where the value goes. The bits of the value part are shown as 0, 1, 2 etc.
   [image: Image courtesy: http://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/]
   In the above figure the green area represents 0 or 1 and white are 0 only. The left side shows hex numbers from 0 to 15 which essentially represents the rotate value(first 4 bits of the 12 bit immediate.)

   3. Now coming to your question, if in the assembly language, you give some number(immediate) that can't be represented in this way of ARM mechanism, you will get error. Your number was 350 which is 101011110 in binary. Note that it has 9 bits(odd number of bits) and as the 4-rotate-bits shifts the 8-bit-value to right by (2 times the value of 4-rotate-bit), you wont get a number having odd number of bits for any value of 12-bit immediate. When you write :

> cmp r0,#350

Arm tries to generate the appropriate twelve-bit field for 350. But if you specify a value which can't be generated, such as 350 (which would require a nine-bit value), an error is generated.